# Mail.ReadBasic equivalent Application scope

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to access email metadata via Microsoft Graph without access to the content of the emails. From the documentation, I've noticed there is a `Mail.ReadBasic` permission that might help but this permission only appears as a Delegated scope.  My service is a backend task so I need an Application scope.

I would really appreciate some help with these issues:

1. Is there a way to enable this `Mail.ReadBasic` permission as an *Application permission*?
2. Can I create custom permission for the application?
3. Can I use `Mail.Read` and enforce selection of fields to reduce it into `Mail.ReadBasic` Permission (otherwise requests will be blocked)
4. Is there any other way to get only the email metadata from the Microsoft Graph (webhooks, access via audit logs, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

1) I am actually the Program Manager in the process of getting this rolled out into Microsoft Graph right now. We are currently deploying this internally to our pre prod env. It is in the deployment process and should be there in all tenants within the next two months.

2 & 3) You cannot create your own custom permissions or reduce fields with Mail.Read.

4) Mail.ReadBasic will get you the email metadata (not body or attachments) with on behalf of flows right now. And soon app-only.

Comment: Wow thats amazing!
Thanks for the quick response and for the roadmap sharing. can't wait to see it up and running :)
Keep up with the great work you are doing!